# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сверстать такой угол?

Tags: css, html5

[image]

Пробовал через hr, возникли проблемы с позиционированием (внутри угла текст)

Comment: Если проблемы с позиционированием, то ознакомьтесь с CSS свойством `position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может вариант через `before` и `after`

```css
.item {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
}

.item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">hello</div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо, вы мне очень помогли

Comment: @Usti пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Сколько вариантов..
Подкину ещё вариант на **background**

```css
.elem {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(0, #000, #000),
    linear-gradient(0, #000, #000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 10% 0, 0 10%;
  background-size: 1px 100%, 100% 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, буду иметь ввиду